# Melhor forma de passar dados para todos os Controllers MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Após fazer login pelo controller **LOGIN**, uma session é criada com o **ID** desse usuário no sistema, apartir desse **ID** posso dar um "fetch" com todas as suas informações, o grande problema é que, ao logar o usuário uma navbar fica no topo do site, ex:

[image: Menu principal do site, após fazer login]

Esse navbar fica no arquivo **header.phtml**, que não é uma "view", mas é chamada quando uma view é instanciada, para mostrar a navbar do usuário em todas as páginas eu tenho que passar um **array** com os dados desse usuário para todos os **controllers** através do controller principal no qual todos extendem, dessa forma eles irão "jogar" essas informações nesse **header.phtml**, qual seria a melhor forma de passar as informações do usuário logado para todos os controllers e exibi-lo nas views

Comment: Você quer saber em qual formato você passa os dados ou outra coisa?Realmente não entendi sua necessidade.

Comment: Você poderia passar pela session também e definir os dados no seu *controller* principal

Comment: Qual o framework você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou fazendo à mão, pensei em passar uma session com um array, mas se os dados forem atualizados? ficariam estáticos.

Comment: Insere uma regra na atualização dos dados em que se o usuário logado atualizar as próprias informações a sessão também é atualizada

Comment: Entendi, pode me dar uma luz sobre como seria essa regra? seria algo como AffectRows? e como eu passaria essa informação? vamos dizer que o usuário atualize seus dados no controller 'Minha Conta', como eu 'Avisaria' outro controller?

Comment: no método que você realiza a atualização do usuário você tem q fazer um `if($_SESSION["Usuario"]["id"]){$_SESSION["Usuario"]["username"] = $_POST["Usuario"]["username"]}` seria alguma coisa nesse sentido, mas sem ver seus códigos fica muito complicado ajudar mais.

Comment: Por hora eu vou indicar sua pergunta para fechar como "não é claro no que está perguntando", mas caso você a edite e deixe mais evidente sua necessidade eu removo meu voto.

Comment: Ok, Acho que isso já basta, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Isso vai depender muito de como você está organizando a sua aplicação. Se você estivesse usando algum framework seria mais fácil sugerir uma solução. Seguem abaixo **possíveis** soluções.

## Opção 1

Crie um objeto que represente o usuário e que possa ser acessado em qualquer parte da aplicação. Algo como *SeuFramewok::$user*. Em cada "page load", inicialize esse objeto a partir dos atributos que você gravou na sessão durante o login. Atualize os atributos da sessão quando o usuário atualizar suas informações. Essa solução é usada pelo YiiFramework (ele tem um objeto Yii::app()->user, acessível globalmente).

## Opção 2

Coloque um objeto que representa o usuário no controlador pai (também carregando a partir da sessão), em uma propriedade de acesso publico. Acesse esse objeto no *header.phtml* através da referência que você tem ao controller.

De um forma ou de outra você precisa gravar os dados do usuário em uma sessão. O interessante é pensar em uma forma de disponibilizar isso facilmente para acesso na sua aplicação. Recomendo utilizar um framework, pois normalmente ele já implementa isso pra você e também lhe uma boa experiência caso deseje desenvolver o seu.

Answer (score 1):

Eu criaria uma classe "usuário", com seus atributos e propriedades, e jogaria em uma session. Eu sobrescreveria a session sempre quando acontecesse alguma atualização.

Um problema desta minha solução seria o custo que estas "sessions" teriam para o servidor, pois imaginem uma aplicação com mais de dez mil acessos simultâneos onde cada usuário teria sua "session" alocada no servidor.

Comment: Vamos dizer que seja uma aplicação grande, então, qual seria a melhor opção?

Comment: Se o objeto não for complexo o custo não será grande. Se o objeto for complexo grave na sessão apenas uma parte dele (serialize apenas os atributos que precisam ser gravados) e carregue a partir dos dados da sessão.